# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Values'

Tags: pandas

I am running the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import read_csv

df = read_csv('demo.csv')
df
plt.hist(df.values)
plt.show()

lower_bound = 0.1
upper_bound = 0.95
res = df.Values.quantile([lower_bound,upper_bound])
res
```

and then I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Values'
```

Answer (score 1):

You tried to use `.Values` with a capital v instead of `.values`. Changing the capital v to a lowercase v should solve fix the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas dataframe object does not have any var as Values, rather it is values with small "v".
For further reference you can refer pandas documentation -

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html